# Mostrar alerta una sola vez

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Estoy trabajando con Codeigniter 3
Tengo el siguiente problema.
Cuando el usuario ingresa a su cuenta, muestra una tabla con proyectos autorizados o no.
[image: Proyectos autorizados o rechazados del usuario test]

Al entrar a ver su proyecto, el sistema debe mostrar una alerta como la siguiente
[image: Alerta de autorizado del proyecto con ID 91]

mi pregunta aqui es la siguiente ¿Como puedo hacer para que esa alerta se muestre una sola vez por ID del proyecto?
Ya lo intenté con cookies, pero se aplican para todos los proyectos autorizados y no por el id del proyecto.

Muestro el codigo donde valido si el proyecto está autorizado

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    foreach ($datos->result() as $datos) {

        if ($datos->status == 'autorizado' && $datos->autorizarPre == 'autorizado') {
            if (!isset($_COOKIE['presupuesto'])) {
                echo '<script> Swal.fire("¡Autorizado!","¡Tu solicitud de presupuesto está autorizado!","success");</script>';
                setcookie('presupuesto', true, time() + 60);
            }

        }
        if ($datos->status == 'regresado' && $datos->autorizarPre == 'regresado') {
            echo '<script> Swal.fire("¡Rechazado!","¡Tu solicitud de presupuesto ha sido rechachaza!","warning");</script>';
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Bienvenidx a la comunidad de Stackoverflow. Por favor lee o visita de nuevo el [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Recuerda resumir tu pregunta para que todos puedan entender el problema que tienes, como incluir solo el código donde crees que puede estar tu problema, retroalimentar tu pregunta con tus avances, referencias, investigaciones, etc. Esto aumentará tus posibilidades de recibir ayuda por parte de la comunidad y además ayudarás a que a la comunidad le sea de utilidad tu pregunta para cuando tengan un problema similar al tuyo.

Answer (score 0):

Ya resolví el problema.
Primero agregué otro campo en mi base de datos llamado mostradoPre.

En mi modelo hice una consulta para que actualizara ese campo con los valores que le pasamos desde el controlador:

```
public function mostrado($id, $mostrado)
    {
        $sql = $this->db->query("UPDATE datos_grals SET mostradoPre = '$mostrado' WHERE id_datos_grals = '$id'");
        return $sql;
    }
```

Una vez que realicé la actualización de datos desde mi modelo, lo que hice a continuación fue agregar lo siguiente en mi controlador. Primero valido si existen por el metodo POST esas variables, si existen entonces esos datos se mandaran al modelo

```
public function prueba()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['prueba']) && isset($_POST['id'])) {
            $prueba = $_POST['prueba'];
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $this->Administracion->mostrado($id, $prueba);
        }
    }
```

Finalmente lo que hice en mi vista fue declarar 2 variables, el ID del proyecto y el dato que quiero que se actualice en mi campo. Todo esto se realiza cuando el usuario da clic en el boton 'Ok' de la alerta. Cuando los datos se envien correctamente, mostrara en consola un mensaje

```
<?php
if ($datos->status == 'autorizado' && $datos->autorizarPre == 'autorizado' && $datos->mostradoPre == null) {
            ?>
                <script>
                var mostrado = 'mostrado';
                var id = '<?php echo $id ?>'
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'success',
                    title: '¡Autorizado!',
                    text: '¡Tu solicitud de presupuesto ha sido autorizado!',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Ok'
                }).then((result) => {
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "post",
                            url: "/portafolio/AgregarProyecto/prueba",
                            data: {
                                prueba: mostrado,
                                id: id
                            },
                            success: function(response) {
                                console.log("Datos enviados correctamente")
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                </script>
<?php
```

Una vez que se mandaron los datos, el campo mostradoPre ahora tiene el valor de 'mostrado'. Para evitar que se vuelva a mostrar la alerta, simplemente hice una condicional como la siguiente.

```
if ($datos->mostradoPre != null) {
//nada
}
```